# Customizing product categories breadcrumb links in Woocommerce via the theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to modify `class-wc-breadcrumb.php` to customize the product category links in the breadcrumb of my products pages.

This file is located in : `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes`

I tried to copy and edit this file in my child theme into: 
 
`wp-content/themes/Divi-child/woocommerce/includes/lass-wc-breadcrumb.php`  
 
**But it doesn't work.**

How to customize product categories breadcrumb links in Woocommerce via my child theme?

Comment: it's not template to just copy it in other folder and expect it to work. what part you changed? `woocommerce` is very changeable plugin and you can use `actions/hooks` to achieve your goal

Comment: I tried to change the following function :
private function add_crumbs_single( $post_id = 0, $permalink = '' )

The goal is to change all links off categories Woocommerce by a static page where i'm showing products

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It is **NOT possible to change cores files** via your theme and it is **strictly prohibited** to do it for many reasons.

#### **Instead** you have **2 options**:

1. Use any available action and filter hooks for WooCommerce breadcrumbs customizations.
2. Customizing WooCommerce template `global/breadcrumb.php` [**via your active child theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

The best choice in your case **is the 1st option**. In the code below you will be able to customize each link of Woocommerce product categories links.

In the code below, I use a foreach loop to iterate through each `$crumb`. Each `$crumb` is an array where:

- `$crumb[0]` is the displayed label name
- `$crumb[1]` is the link (or the url) that will be changed using `$crumbs[$key][1]`…

We will check that the current `$crumb[0]` is a product category name before allowing to customize it's link in `$crumbs[$key][1]`.

> You will have to set your new links for each product category **adding your own necessary code** to this filtered hooked function example.

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'custom_breadcrumb', 10, 2 );
function custom_breadcrumb( $crumbs, $object_class ){
    // Loop through all $crumb
    foreach( $crumbs as $key => $crumb ){
        $taxonomy = 'product_cat'; // The product category taxonomy

        // Check if it is a product category term
        $term_array = term_exists( $crumb[0], $taxonomy );

        // if it is a product category term
        if ( $term_array !== 0 && $term_array !== null ) {

            // Get the WP_Term instance object
            $term = get_term( $term_array['term_id'], $taxonomy );

            // HERE set your new link with a custom one
            $crumbs[$key][1] = home_url( '/'.$term->slug.'/' ); // or use all other dedicated functions
        }
    }

    return $crumbs;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works.

Comment: Awesome, it was exactly what i needed.
I add the following code into the function :

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous option to change the option..

For this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'jk_woocommerce_breadcrumbs' );
function jk_woocommerce_breadcrumbs() {
return array(
        'delimiter'   => ' &#47; ',
        'wrap_before' => '<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb">',
        'wrap_after'  => '</nav>',
        'before'      => '',
        'after'       => '',
        'home'        => _x( 'Home', 'breadcrumb', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
}
```

You can change all your content via this.

For more information :- https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/customise-the-woocommerce-breadcrumb/

Comment: Thank you, I read this page, but what's happen if I do updates ?
Do my code will not be erased ?

Comment: you need to perform this in child theme and there is 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults' as filter which you can modify according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'ts_woocommerce_breadcrumbs_change' );
function ts_woocommerce_breadcrumbs_change() {
    return array(
            'delimiter'   => '  ',
            'wrap_before' => '<ul class="breadcrumb load-animate theme-animate fadeInUp animated" style="animation-delay: 0.3s;">',
            'wrap_after'  => '</ul>',
            'before'      => '<li> ',
            'after'       => '</li>',
            'home'        => _x( 'Home', 'breadcrumb', 'woocommerce' ),
            
        );
}
```