# How can I add a custom attribute to WooCommerce breadcrumb?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy, breadcrumbs

I've been trying to display the product brand in the breadcrumb (for single product template only).

WooCommerce breadcrumb only gives me the product category (Home > Category > Product Title)
With RankMath plugin, I can set the product main taxonomy to "Brands" (Using "Perfect Brands for Woocommerce", pwb_brand attribute) and I get Home > Brand > Product Title).
My products also have a product attribute "Marque" (meaning brand) containing the brand name, I can access it in PHP with

```
global $product;
$custom_attribute = $product->get_attribute( 'marque' );
echo $custom_attribute;
```

Reading [WooCommerce - Change specific category link in Breadcrumbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71113349/woocommerce-change-specific-category-link-in-breadcrumbs) and [Customizing product categories breadcrumb links in Woocommerce via the theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886118/customizing-product-categories-breadcrumb-links-in-woocommerce-via-the-theme), I know that I can modify the default WooCommerce Breadcrumb through functions.php

Do you think it's possible to customize the following code snippet (for functions.php) to my case ?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'custom_breadcrumb', 10, 2 );
function custom_breadcrumb( $crumbs, $object_class ){
    // Loop through all $crumb
    foreach( $crumbs as $key => $crumb ){
        $taxonomy = 'product_cat'; // The product category taxonomy

        // Check if it is a product category term
        $term_array = term_exists( $crumb[0], $taxonomy );

        // if it is a product category term
        if ( $term_array !== 0 && $term_array !== null ) {

            // Get the WP_Term instance object
            $term = get_term( $term_array['term_id'], $taxonomy );

            // HERE set your new link with a custom one
            $crumbs[$key][1] = home_url( '/'.$term->slug.'/' ); // or use all other dedicated functions
        }
    }

    return $crumbs;
}
```

Other solution would be creating a child template of [woocommerce/global/breadcrumb.php](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-global-breadcrumb.html) and find a way to edit this file in order to add the following breadcrumb item :

```
if ( is_product() ) {
            global $product;
            echo '<a href="/marque/'.$product->get_attribute( 'marque' ).'/">'.$product->get_attribute( 'marque' ).'</a>';
        }
```

In the breadcrumb loop, but all I've succeeded doing was appending the brand name and link to the start or the end of every breadcrumb item at the same time. Any idea on how to integrate this ?

Thanks in advance for all your feedbacks and suggestions.

Comment: I ended up butchering something in the breadcrumb.php child template and it works, my only problem though is for the URL I use the get-attribute method :
<a href="/marque/'.$product->get_attribute( 'marque' ).'/">'
And I wish I could get the slug : if attribute marque is "Anita Ko" I want to get "anita-ko". Any ideas on how to do the right call ?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308552/how-to-get-woocommerce-product-attribute-slug https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240283/get-product-attributes-for-current-product-and-store-it-in-a-variable